# DST-agnostic time in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, dst

I have a scheduling class that takes a `datetime.time` object and runs a task every day at the specified time.

```py
import time
import datetime as dt


class Scheduler:
  def set_time(self, day_time):
    self._day_time = day_time
    self._last_execution = None

  def run(self, f):
    while True:
      time.sleep(10)

      now = dt.datetime.now(dt.UTC)
      today = now.date()

      # Don't run on weekends
      if today.weekday() > 4:
        continue

      # First execution: it can run anytime within the first 5 minutes after the expected time
      if self._last_execution is None:
        begin = dt.datetime.combine(today, self._day_time)
        end = begin + dt.timedelta(minutes=5)
        if begin <= now < end:
          self._last_execution = now
          f()
        else:
          continue

      # Later executions
      scheduled = dt.datetime.combine(today, self._day_time)
      if self._last_execution < scheduled and now >= scheduled:
        self._last_execution = now
        f()


scheduler = Scheduler()
scheduler.set_time(dt.time(8, 30, tzinfo=my_timezone))
scheduler.run(lambda: print("This is printed every day at 8:30"))
```

Assume that this service stays up for years.

Obviously, the problem is the `my_timezone` variable. I would like this task to be run every day at the same time, no matter whether we are in DST or not (which by the way means that if my task is to be run at 2:30 in the morning, it will be run twice when moving from DST to non-DST, and skipped when moving from non-DST to DST).

Internally, `scheduler` compares the time specified at set up time with `dt.datetime.now(dt.UTC)`.

I wonder what is the best way to deal with this. Is there a `tzinfo` I can specify to account for DST?

Comment: Timezone specifiers like `"Europe/Paris"`, `"America/Chicago"`, etc etc, all account for DST in the relevant location. So you can use whichever of those is relevant for you as your `tzinfo`. The thing that would need some care is how to run the task twice on the "fall back" day: the `time` object has a `fold` attribute which is used to distinguish between the two 2.30s on that day.

Comment: @slothrop thanks. So setting `my_timezone` to the geographical specifier such as "Europe/Paris" is sufficient for what I need? I was not completely sure because the creation of `dt.time(8, 30, tzinfo=my_timezone)` is performed only once at the beginning and was afraid that the timezone would be considered only then.

(I'm aware of the `fold` attribute)

Comment: Can you add to your question the code that does the time comparison?

Comment: @slothrop: done (I simplified a lot from my actual code that contains irrelevant details)

Comment: Thanks. There are a couple of issues I think: (1) on the "fall back" day, this won't trigger the second run (because your `_day_time` will have the default value of `fold=0`), (2) `today` looks like it should be "today" in local time, not in UTC. For example, if we're running in the America/NewYork timezone and it's 2023-07-19 22:00 locally, then `today` will be 2023-07-20 and so `begin` (or `scheduled`) will be 24 hours later than it should be.

Comment: But actually: `# Don't run on weekends` might remove some complexity. Is there any place where the timezone change doesn't happen at a weekend?

Comment: Thanks for your help. (1) is not an issue (especially because, as you noted, the task does not run on weekends). About (2) I think I see the conceptual problem, but I don't see the practical problem; it will still be consistent and run every day at the requested time, right?

Comment: (2) will be a problem if the scheduled time is such that local "today" is not the same as "UTC today" at the time the task is meant to run. In the previous example, if we're in New York and our scheduled time is 22:00, then `begin` and `scheduled` will **always** be later than `now` and the task will never run.

Comment: I see now. Are you suggesting to define `now` with the same timezone I use for `self._day_time`?

Also, back to the original question, are you saying that I should use `pytz` to obtain the "political" timezones, such as `pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris')`?

Comment: (i) Yes that's right, (ii) from Python 3.9 onwards, it's better to use `zoneinfo`: `pytz` is in maintenance mode. https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind posting this as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zoneinfo` (in Python >= 3.9), and `pytz` (a third-party module prevalently used before `zoneinfo` was incorporated), give easy access to [IANA timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#Time_Zone_abbreviations) such as `"Europe/Paris"`, `"America/Chicago"` etc etc. These timezone specifications which include the DST rules for the appropriate location.

Constructing a timezone object in this way, and using it as the `tzinfo` attribute of your `self._day_time`, would allow your scheduler to operate with times that take account of DST rules. You're using `datetime.datetime.combine`, which by default will use the `tzinfo` of its time argument and apply it to the result ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine)): that's just what we want here.

For example:

```
import datetime
import zoneinfo

t0 = datetime.time(11, 15, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('Europe/Paris'))

# Combine this time with d0 (winter, no DST) and d1 (summer, DST in force)
d0 = datetime.date(2023, 1, 1)
d1 = datetime.date(2023, 7, 1)
print(datetime.datetime.combine(d0, t0))
print(datetime.datetime.combine(d1, t0))
```

which prints:

```
2023-01-01 11:15:00+01:00
2023-07-01 11:15:00+02:00
```

Note the UTC offsets in the output there: DST is indeed being taken into account as required.

Based on the comments, the task does not run on weekends, and so we don't deal here with the complexity of what should/does happen on a DST changeover day. That would be problematic with the current code: as [@FObersteiner's answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76727499/765091), adding positive `timedelta` to datetimes in a timezone with daylight saving can paradozically result in moving *back* in time, so that `end` would be earlier than `begin`!

---

Not directly related to your original question, but in your code logic it's important that the date argument given to `combine` reflects the day on which you want the event to take place. So this code is problematic in certain circumstances:

```
now = dt.datetime.now(dt.UTC)
today = now.date()
```

For example, imagine that `self._day_time` has been given as `time(22, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('America/NewYork')`.

If it's now 22:00 on 2023-07-20 in New York (and so the task is supposed to fire), then in UTC it's 02:00 on 2023-07-21.

So your `today` is `2023-07-21`, and hence your `begin` and `scheduled` in local time are `2023-07-21 22:00`. That's 24 hours after they should be.

Instead, `today` should be determined using a datetime with the same time zone as `self._day_time`.

Comment: not sure if that prevents problems if a task is scheduled on a DST transition. Let's say the transition happens at 2 am, there are two transitions in a year (DST on and off) and the task is scheduled to run at 2 am. Wouldn't you get one day in a year with two executions and one day in that year without an execution?

Comment: *Wouldn't you get one day in a year with two executions and one day in that year without an execution?* From the comments (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76719932/dst-agnostic-time-in-python/76721008?noredirect=1#comment135258342_76719932) this turns out not to be an issue in practice, since the task doesn't run at weekends. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Uh are you sure all DST transitions happen on weekends, for all timezones that have DST? ;-)

Comment: @FObersteiner there are rules that specify which times are valid during DST transitions. A time with a *timezone name*, not offset, is unique. You'll never get two executions of `2023-10-29 03:30 at Europe/Athens`

Comment: @FObersteiner I'm going by OP's stipulation in the comments that this issue isn't a concern for them.

Comment: Problems occur if the *offset* is used instead of the timezone name, because the local execution time will move by 1 hour. There won't be duplicate executions though

Comment: There indeed won't be duplicate executions. (In the question and comments, you'll see that OP originally indicated the task *should* execute twice on a "fall back" day, I observed that it wouldn't, then OP clarified that that wasn't after all a problem).

Comment: I'm not fully convinced this is save. It might be *ok* within the OP's constraints. But be aware that you can create non-existing datetimes with Python's timedelta arithmetic. Time zone rules don't protect you here.

Comment: @FObersteiner I thought that Python was smart enough to add a timedelta across a DST boundary, but I tested it and I was wrong. You need to convert to UTC, add, and convert back.

Comment: @FObersteiner's answer clarifies the situation very clearly. slothrop, can you please update your answer referring to that problem? I will accept anyway this answer since it answers directly my question.

Comment: sure, updated it to indicate the problems that would arise on a DST transition day.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an illustration of my comment. If you schedule something ***on time only***, you're in for surprises, especially if you play with timedelta arithmetic:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

start = datetime(2023,10,29,1,45,tzinfo=ZoneInfo("Europe/Berlin"))

for i in range(10):
    print(start+timedelta(minutes=i*20))
# 2023-10-29 01:45:00+02:00
# 2023-10-29 02:05:00+02:00
# 2023-10-29 02:25:00+02:00
# 2023-10-29 02:45:00+02:00
# 2023-10-29 03:05:00+01:00 # <<-- "naive timedelta arithmetic" is wrong !
# 2023-10-29 03:25:00+01:00
# 2023-10-29 03:45:00+01:00
# 2023-10-29 04:05:00+01:00
# 2023-10-29 04:25:00+01:00
# 2023-10-29 04:45:00+01:00
```

As @MarkRansom commented, you'll have to convert to UTC before adding durations:

```py
def aware_add(dt, duration):
    return (dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo("UTC")) + duration).astimezone(dt.tzinfo)

for i in range(10):
    print(aware_add(start, timedelta(minutes=i*20)))
# 2023-10-29 01:45:00+02:00
# 2023-10-29 02:05:00+02:00
# 2023-10-29 02:25:00+02:00
# 2023-10-29 02:45:00+02:00 # <<-- after 2:59:59, 2:00:00 follows ...
# 2023-10-29 02:05:00+01:00 # <<-- note the duplicate times ...
# 2023-10-29 02:25:00+01:00 # only the combination of UTC offset and time is unique !
# 2023-10-29 02:45:00+01:00
# 2023-10-29 03:05:00+01:00
# 2023-10-29 03:25:00+01:00
# 2023-10-29 03:45:00+01:00
```